# Eclipse - No JVM was found after reformat

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I had to reformat my computer, and I went from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 in the process.

I reinstalled the 64bit version of eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1/eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip

I then installed the 64bit version of Java JRE and JDK. Which can be found respectively:

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
- C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25

However, upon starting eclipse I'm receiving the following error:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations:
>   C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your
>   current PATH.

**So I opened up CMD and tested my paths, and they're setup correctly.**

-- Every question I've seen about this issue, the problem was the user installing the x86 version of eclipse and x64 java, or x86 java and x64 eclipse, etc, but this is not the case in my issue.

Comment: set `%JAVA_HOME%`? How did you "test your paths"? If you just type `javaw.exe` at the command prompt, does it work?

Comment: Also, what is pointing into your `eclipse` directory (the path in the error message you are getting refers to it rather than where you rjre is intalled)? This does not seem to be right. There must be a setting somewhere, that makes eclipse think you have java installed in that location.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME variable is set, and adding the arguments to the .ini file did not change the results.

Answer (score 0):

If a JVM is installed in the `eclipse/jre` directory, Eclipse will use it; otherwise the launcher will consult the `eclipse.ini` file and the `system path` variable.

**Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable!**

([more info](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM))

Either edit `eclipse.ini` (this file is in the installation directory `configuration` folder) file and enter following lines

```
-vm
C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
```

Path should point to your JDK installation.

Source : [Eclipse Wiki Documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example)

Also found following in the `readme_eclipse.html` file

**Specifying the Java virtual machine**

Here is a typical Eclipse command line:

```
eclipse -vm c:\jdk6u22\jre\bin\javaw
```

Tip: It's generally a good idea to explicitly specify which Java VM to use when running Eclipse. This is achieved with the "-vm" command line argument as illustrated above. If you don't use "-vm", Eclipse will look on the O/S path. When you install other Java-based products, they may change your path and could result in a different Java VM being used when you next launch Eclipse.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME variable is set, and adding the arguments to the .ini file did not change the results. –

Comment: Yes setting `JAVA_HOME` will not work. Try adding in .ini file. Add this at the top. Also make sure there is new line between `vm` and your path.

Comment: I ended up deleting and reinstalling java and it worked magically.